# Query related to the average number of children that can buy a toy

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation

There are $N$ children. On a particular special day (Christmas e.g.) they are placed in a line (one dimensional) according to uniform distribution. The start of the row is denoted to be the origin of one dimensional space and the length of the line is $L$. After placing them in the line they receive some money according to their distance from the origin. This means that a child that is $m$ meters away from the origin will receive $K-m$ dollars. Now if a child has received $\geq P$ (which is less than $K$) dollars then he can buy a toy. Further it is assumed that if a child has received more than $P$ dollars then he can give the extra money to a child that has received less than $P$ dollars so that the other child (which receives the money from the donor child) can also buy the toy. In this situation my questions are

What will be the average number of children that can buy the toy on any special day?

Can we have an analytical expression for this answer?

Is the provided information sufficient to solve the problem?

Is there any book or paper that has similar kind of problem where I can look for its solution?

Your help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The number of children who can afford to buy a toy (including those who receive donations) is:

$$\min\left(\bigg\lfloor2\left(\frac{K-P}L\right)N\bigg\rfloor, N\right)$$

If $P<K-\frac 12L$, then every child can afford to buy a toy (including those who receive donations).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please provide the extended proof or some reference where I can look for it. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You're welcome. Draw a graph - horizontal axis for distance $m$ (from $0$ to $L$), and vertical axis for amount to be received. Graph is a straight downward-sloping line from $(0,K)$ to $(L,K-L)$. The rest follows quite easily.

Comment: Do you assume that the total amount to be distributed among all child is $K$. I am asking because this is not right assumption. In my case the initial amount received by a child is dependent only on its distance from the origin. If you have not assumed the above assumption then I request you to please add the said graph to your answer. Thank you

Comment: No that is not the assumption. The straight line graphs is just $K-m$, as given, where $m$ is the horizontal axis.